# TcmItemsOldVersions returns 10000

Tags: 2013-sp1, purgetool

See screenshot below:

[image]

The command returned 10.000 for the second time now. Is there a possibility to change this limit? And is there an option to check which components are already cleaned up?

Comment: Ah, I think I found it! There is a parameter -MaxResolvedItemscount, the description says the Default value is 100.000. I think there is a type, that should be 10000. Will test it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for MaxResolvedItemsCount is 10,000. There is a hard upper limit and it is 100,000. If you'll try to set MaxResolvedItemsCount to value >100,000, default value will be used instead (e.g. 10,000).